# DropDownList doesn't want to be set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My dropDown list doesn't want to have default value!

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.unit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.unit.id, selectUnit)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.unit.id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Show me the right list but none is selected.

I get my SelectList by using ViewBag:

```
@{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectUnit = ViewBag.Unit;
}
```

When I breakpoint the cshtml, Model.unit.id is 4 and selectUnit  have one item with 4 as value.

When I do

```
@selectUnit.Where(x => x.Value == Model.unit.id.ToString()).First().Text
```

it selects the right text value!

Lats think: this is my Unit model:

```
public class Unit
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public IList<Unit> children { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance folks, I'm becoming crasy

**EDIT:**

```
public class ModelPassedTroughTheView
{
    ...
    public Unit unit { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT 2: Full code:**

Edit page:
    @model BE.DealerGroupSAP

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resources.Admin.DealerGroup_Edit;

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectUnit = ViewBag.Unit;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>@ViewBag.Title</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.unit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.unit.id, selectUnit)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.unit.id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Global.Save_Edits" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Model passer trough view:

```
public class DealerGroupSAP
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Unit unit { get; set; }
}
```

Unit object:

```
public class Unit
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public IList<Unit> children { get; set; }
}
```

Controller's content:

```
ViewBag.Unit = GetUnits();
return View(BL.AnomalyBL.GetAllSAPResponsible(id));
```

Comment: The model in the view is not `Unit` - its a class that contains `Unit` (and best guess that is a field not a property with `{ get; set; }`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thank you! I've updated the post. Model passed contains one Unit field that has it's acessors, so I didn't solve the issue

Comment: The code you have shown should work fine (and when you say _but none is selected_, I assume you mean the first option is selected?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I've paste all code. When I mean no elemtn is selected you're right, first element is selected by default :-)

Comment: You have a `ViewBag` property named `Unit` which may be causing a conflict with the property `unit`. Try changing it to (say) `ViewBag.UnitList` and use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectUnit = ViewBag.UnitList;`

Comment: stephenMuecke Bingo! but I still don't understand. Does .net mixed the Model parameter With viewbag data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133972/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-clement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your model has a property named `unit` and your also passing the `SelectList` view a `ViewBag` property named `Unit` (the model binding features of MVC are case insensitive.

Change the name of the `ViewBag` property to (say)

```
ViewBag.UnitList = GetUnits();
```

and in the view

```
@{ IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectUnit = ViewBag.UnitList }
```

and the correct option will be selected.

---

To explain what is happening internally:

The `DropDownListFor()` method determines the `defaultValue` (selected item) by first checking values in `ModelState` (which in your case do not exist), then checking `ViewData`. Because `ViewData` contains a key/value pair for `Unit`, which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and does not contain a property `id`, the `defaultValue` is `null`and the method uses the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` you passed to the view to build the `<option>` elements, none of which have a `Selected = true` value, so the first option is selected because something has to be.

Changing the `ViewBag` property to to (say) `UnitList` means the method does not find a matching key for `unit` in `ViewData` and now inspects the model for `unit.id`, which exists, and sets `defaultValue = 4`. Because `defaultValue` is not `null`, a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is generated internally, and the corresponding `SelectListItem` has its `Selected` property set to `true`.

To understand how this all works in detail, you can inspect the source code for [SelectExtensions](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) - in particular the `private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal()` method.

As a final note, this is just one more reason why you should **always** use a view model.

Comment: As a side note, this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxriS9) might be of interest